# Errors management in a springboot + kafka application

Tags: java, error-handling, apache-kafka

I am trying to create an error management system in my application.

I receive data from IBM AS400, we have developped a connector from AS400 to Kafka.

My pipeline looks like this:

[image]

There is two possibilities, either we expect the error and we create a specific structure, or we don't expect it, because we didn't have to face it before.

I have listed the following possible errors:

- Corrupted input data that leads to application error => Formatted Exception
- System failover (database, service, ...) => Unknown exception

The question is, how do I have to manage the errors afterwards ? What are the considerations that I have to take into account to manage the errors without any human/manual replay mechanism.

If the error is in the case of a formatted exception and it occurs, how can I continue the treatment ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: In general, you would send the data to a dead-letter-queue topic, then you need to manually inspect and replay at a later time (assuming the data can be made valid). If a downstream system failed, you shouldn't be consuming and commiting offsets anyway

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know if there is other common errors that I could expect ?

Comment: Another question, why don't we have to continue consuming and commiting offsets anyway ?

Comment: There are many exception types in Kafka outside just consumer ones. But if a downstream system fails, and you read and process a message, then you'd be losing and skipping messages.

Comment: Do you have an idea about, how to manage the replay ? lets say that I commit an offset every 500 records, and that only 1 record is in error. Do I have to replay all the records ? If it's the case, how can I avoid duplication ?

Comment: Have you looked into Kafka transactions or idempotent producers?

Comment: Yes thanks for the hint. What about the replay ? Do I have to replay all the records, or only one record ?

Comment: If a record in a transaction fails, then it is rolled back, and no records are sent. Otherwise, you would have to resend the whole batch of records. The first "half" of which could be duplicated.

Comment: So this is the case where we send data unitarly, do you have an idea about sending data by block of 500 messages for example

Comment: As I mentioned, regardless of the block size, any one of those messages could potentially fail. Depending on how you configure the clients, you either have to deal with duplicate or dropped records in the worst case scenario.